# images rotation to the right

Tags: javascript

I have 4 images in an HTML page: 1.png, 2.png, 3.png and 4.png. I want when the user click in the image 3, a rotation to the right of the various images is performed.
(replace the image 1 with image 3, image 2 by image 1,image 4 by image 2 and image 3 by image 4).

this is the code I tried, but It won't work :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function rotation()
            {
                img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
                img2 = document.getElementById('img2');
                img3 = document.getElementById('img3');
                img4 = document.getElementById('img4');

                img2.parentNode.appendChild(img4);
                img1.parentNode.appendChild(img2);
                img3.parentNode.appendChild(img1);
                img4.parentNode.appendChild(img3);

            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            table
            {
                margin-left:auto;
                margin-right:auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="centrer">
            <tr>
                <td><img src="exercice1/1.png" alt="Image 1" id="img1"></td>
                <td><img src="exercice1/2.png" alt="Image 2" id="img2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="exercice1/3.png" alt="Image 3" id="img3" onclick="rotation()"></td>
                <td><img src="exercice1/4.png" alt="Image 4" id="img4"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is when I click for the first time on image 3 the images are ordered like this:

```
2
1  3  4
```

and in the second time they ordred like this:

```
2  1  3  4
```

and I want them to be ordered like this:

before rotation:

```
1  2
3  4
```

after rotation :

```
3  1
4  2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And what is happening instead? My guess is that the parentNode of the elements are changing when you move them:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function rotation()
            {
                var img1 = document.getElementById('img1'),
                    img2 = document.getElementById('img2'),
                    img3 = document.getElementById('img3'),
                    img4 = document.getElementById('img4'),
                    cont1 = img1.parentNode,
                    cont2 = img2.parentNode,
                    cont3 = img3.parentNode,
                    cont4 = img4.parentNode;

                cont2.appendChild(img4);
                cont1.appendChild(img2);
                cont3.appendChild(img1);
                cont4.appendChild(img3);

            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            table
            {
                margin-left:auto;
                margin-right:auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="centrer">
            <tr>
                <td><img src="exercice1/1.png" alt="Image 1" id="img1"></td>
                <td><img src="exercice1/2.png" alt="Image 2" id="img2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="exercice1/3.png" alt="Image 3" id="img3" onclick="rotation()"></td>
                <td><img src="exercice1/4.png" alt="Image 4" id="img4"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: see the modification I made

Comment: Yes, that's the only fix needed, keeping track of the parent nodes as well as the child nodes, so the child nodes don't get confused when swapping the locations (since in the last step the 4th image has already been moved).

Comment: you dhould modify this line of img 4 to document.getElementById('img3') otherwise this code works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Change the `src` attribute instead. Like so:

```
function rotation()
{
    img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
    img2 = document.getElementById('img2');
    img3 = document.getElementById('img3');
    img4 = document.getElementById('img4');

    src1 = img1.src;
    src2 = img2.src;
    src3 = img3.src;
    src4 = img4.src;

    img2.src = src4;
    img1.src = src2;
    img3.src = src1;
    img4.src = src3;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gJK8D/2/

Comment: I like this way, pretty clever

Comment: unforthunatly I can't change the images source because I have other function which won't work if I changed the images source you can see it in my previous post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14989245/move-the-mouse-pointer-over-an-image/

Comment: also if I used this method I will face a problem that when the image 1 take the image 3 place I have to click in the next time on the image 1 to do the rotation